# What does the symbol <?> mean?

Tags: java, android

While doing some android app development, I encounter the parameter `AdapterView< ? >` test. My question is what exactly does `< ? >` mean or do because I also see it in many other places such as a Map where it is `Map< String ,? >`.

Comment: hey thanks for answering but is it possible for you to provide me a link?

Comment: Ok I got it thanks but can you put your explanation in the answer on the bottom so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: You can get explanation here: [use this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632833/java-syntax-explanation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In generic code, the question mark (**?**), called the **wildcard**, represents an unknown type.

The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable; sometimes as a return type.

So in order to answer the question: it is a **Wildcard**-> [Official Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) so you can handle classes event when you dont know the type.